# MATLAB Not properly sending HTTP POST requests

Tags: matlab, http, post

I'm currently trying to build a MATLAB based system to interface with the API of my stock broker. I'm however running into quite some issues with sending the http post requests to the server.

I already have it working perfectly when testing with POSTMAN, but for some reason it keeps refusing my MATLAB send requests. I now testing the actual requests through PIPEDREAM which lets me view the http request.

Image of the good and bad requests:

[image: Image of the good and bad requests]

The Left is an image of my postman requests which it perfectly processes as JSON strings. However my MATLAB requests are not processed properly and also are 10 characters longer than the actual string value.

The (trimmed) code to send the requests can be seen here.

```
% http request classes
import matlab.net.*
import matlab.net.http.*

% prepare payload
username = "usr";
password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    
login_payload = struct("username", username, "password", password);

request = RequestMessage('POST', [ bunchOfHeaders ],  jsonencode(login_payload));
% Send request to login api
[login_resp, c, h] = request.send("https://trading.somebroker.com/login/secure/login");
```

Does anyone have any clue what could be happening here? If I set the content-lenght to the "correct" length (same as length(login_payload)) it says my length is wrong even though my postman requests seem to not struggle with this.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer... Matlabs http stuff is absolutely braindead.

I had a closer look into the raw intercepted messages (pipedream just sends your request back to you and you can view it with string(login_resp)).

For some god darn reason matlab encases the json string with "s which makes the receiver treat the whole body as a string. This is caused by setting the "content-type" to "application/json". changing the content-type to "text/plain" did not encase it in "s and completely solved my issue